# Json Deserialization and controlling the instantiation

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, json.net

I am converting code that was written using NewtonSoft.JsonNet. This is actually a custom Json Media Type Formatter. I have to change it because Json.Net has proven that its performance is very poor under load. Many comparison on the Internet is also proving this.

Anyway, I have a base type called `CatalogueItem`. Three types are derived from this type and are called `ContainerItem`, `SectionItem`, and `RefresherItem`. Based on a property in the Json object which is called `itemType` we decide which sub-class must be instantiated.

```
var type = (string)jsonObject.Property("itemType");

        switch (type)
        {
            case "Container":
                return new ContainerItem();
            case "Section":
                return new SectionItem();
            case "Refresher":
                return new RefresherItem();
        }
```

We used to do this with creating a custom `CustomCreationConverter`, and adding it to `Serializer.Converters` collection of `Json.Net.Serializer`. Trying to get rid of Json.Net, I am using `ServiceStack.Text`, but I don't know how can I control the type that is being generated using it. Can anyone please help me with this?

p.s. I found this post on StackOverflow in which similar issue has been answered. However, I get the json from a third-party web service so I cannot include type names in it. Plus, I cannot use the generic version of `JsConfig` because `MediaTypeFormatter` does not have any generic methods.

Comment: Even though it did not help you, can you link your question to the other post(s) you mentioned that you looked at?  This might help others to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend avoiding trying to coerce your JSON Serializer to your models and just use DTO's that map 1:1 to the wire format than use plain C# to map the typed DTO's to your desired domain models.

With that said, depending on what the JSON and DTO's look like you may be able to use one of:

```
JsConfig<CatalogueItem>.RawDeserializeFn
JsConfig<CatalogueItem>.DeSerializeFn
JsConfig<CatalogueItem>.OnDeserializedFn
```

Otherwise you can parse JSON dynamically using JsonObject, [here's an example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/CentroidTests.cs).